# htaccess rewrite rule accept % character in parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm creating a rewrite rule which should include a parameter which could contain the character `%`, however when I add it to my rule it breaks my website and every page returns an error:

```
RewriteRule ^sale/([a-zA-Z0-9_-%]+)$ browse.php?id=$1
```

I wanted the parameter to be able to include characters, digits 0 to 9 and special characters `-`, `_` and `%`.

If I remove the `%` it works fine but obviously I want that to be accepted as a character for example url :

http://www.websitename.com/sale/test%20parameter

Answer (score 2):

Apache translates percentage-encoded character inside a url before feeding it to mod_rewrite. So if you want to accept `%20` in your urls you need to just add a space inside your RewriteRule. Note however that space is also to separate the regulare expression and the replacement string in RewriteRule, so in the case of a space you need to escape it using `\`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `B flag` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b